# youtube-dl - 'v' is not recognized as an internal or external command / 'feature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube-dl

I had a problem with youtube-dl (python package) when I tried to download a Youtube video, and here are the error messages:

```
'v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

and

```
'feature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Where could these errors come from?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error and was able to download the file by entering the following command in command line and pressing enter:

```
youtube-dl **video identifier**
```

where video identifier is the series of digits that comes after "v=". For example, if your video URL is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg --> the identifier is dMH0bHeiRNg and the whole command is:

```
youtube-dl dMH0bHeiRNg
```